# natbib package not working shows [?] and no list of references

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

After trying for a couple of hours, I've come here to ask for help. This is my first time using LaTeX. I downloaded a template for my thesis, thinking I just needed to write over it. However, I've had many issues. Specifically, I need assistance with the natbib-package. Firstly, it displays [?] in the PDF, and there is no list of references. Here are the relevant codes:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\newcommand{\tReferenceStyle}{ieee}
\usepackage[numbers,square,super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{singlespace}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
{\bibliographystyle{BibTeX/acfrplainnat}}    
\begin{raggedright}     
    \bibliography{BibTeX/library}
\end{raggedright}

\end{singlespace}
```

here is library.bib

```
    @article{1839Becquerel,
  title={Synthesis of soluble organic semiconductors and study on its application in optoelectronic materials},
  author={Becquerel, E and others},
  journal={CR Acad. Sci},
  volume={9},
  pages={561--567},
  year={1839}
}
```

and how I cited

```
The first \ac{PEC} experiment was performed in 1839 by Becquerel \cite{1839Becquerel}...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. After running LaTeX, did you run BibTeX (to create the formatted bibliography), followed by two more LaTeX runs (first to typeset the formatted bibliography created by BibTeX, and second to resolve the citation call-outs)?

Comment: @Micro Thank you! Now, after I run BibTeX, the List of References appears, but without numbering, like [], and in the main text, the citation is still [?].

Comment: Did you run LaTeX *twice* after running BibTeX?

Comment: Now I did. when I run LaTex, it comes with 2 errors. 1. ''! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option 'pdftex',(hyperref) because pdfTex in PEF mode is not detected.''   2. ''! pdfTeX error (\pefobj): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0)...''

Comment: Well, it's time to stop using the `pdftex` option, isn't it? Why would you specify this option to begin with? Incidentally, the sample code you posted doesn't involve the `hyperref` package in any way. This makes is well-nigh impossible to guess what exactly you're doing with regard to that package.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question, but the issue is resolved now. Thanks! It generated the correct format with [1]. However, the sequence of the references is not correct; the first citation in the text shows [2], and the second one shows [1]. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a "correct" or "incorrect" sequence. In particular, do you want the references to be sorted alphabetically by authors' surnames, or do you want them to be listed in the order they're first cited? Hint: The `acfrplainnat` bib style (like the `plain` and `plainnat` styles) is programmed to sort the entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. If that's not what you want, then you probably shouldn't be using the `acfrplainnat` bib style to begin with. Conversely, if you're *required* to use the `acfrplainnat` bib style, then just accept the resulting sequencing.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I thought that the bibliography styles weren't linked to the order in which they are listed. I want the references to be listed in the order of their citation sequences. I should look for another bibliography style.

Comment: Do investigate if a style called `acfrunsrtnat` exists. If not, give `unsrtnat` a shot.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about 'acfrunsrtnat.' It didn't make any changes when using 'unsrtnat.' Should an 'unsrtnat.bst' file be created?

Comment: Well, after you changed the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, did you re-run BibTeX, followed by two more runs (not just one more run) of LaTeX? Hint: BibTeX gets its instructions on what to do from the argument of `\bibliographystyle`. It you change the bib style, you *must* re-run BibTeX in order to get the new bib style to actually do its work.

Comment: Yes I have. The first citation in the text is still referenced as [2], while the second one is denoted as [1]. But in the list of references, [2] appears now before [1].

Comment: Well, I ran it a couple more times. Now it generated in the order that I wanted. Thank you very much! This is my first time writing with LaTeX, there are so many small things to keep track of.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue (a failure to run BibTeX) was addressed in the comments.